# Berkeley Database Java set sort directory

Tags: java, berkeley-db

How could I set the sort directory in Berkeley?

I am using Berkeley Java (je-5.0.58.jar) to store my data, and got exception 

`sort: write failed: /tmp/sort7LMPoZ: No space left on device`

By looking at the manual, the records are sorted first by key before writing. So is there a way to define the sort directory (the default is /tmp) when creating the database.

(I am running my script on server, there is enough disk space at my /home directory, but not at /tmp, and I can not enlarge /tmp since I am not root user.)

Thanks.

Comment: I found that in classic Berkeley DB, the docs say "The environment variable `TMPDIR` may be used as a directory in which to create temporary backing files." However, I didn't find any mention of this in the Berkeley Java docs.